# What options control PairedHistogram axes style?

Tags: graphics

What options control axes style in PairedHistogram? Here's the [online doc](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PairedHistogram.html). I'm trying to control axes color, thickness, and probably font size on the tick marks. but the options are confusing me:

```
data = Transpose@
   Table[{RandomInteger[{1, 10}], RandomInteger[{1, 10}]}, {100}];
PairedHistogram[data[[1]], data[[2]],
 PlotRange -> {All, All}, BarOrigin -> "XAxis", 
 ChartBaseStyle -> {EdgeForm[None]}, 
 ChartStyle -> {{Blue, Orange}, None, 
   None},(*ChartElementFunction-> \
ChartElementDataFunction["SegmentScaleRectangle","Segments"-> \
5,"ColorScheme"->"SolarColors"],*)
 ChartLegends -> {"A", "B"}, 
 ImageSize -> 300, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: AxesStyle -> Red ??

Comment: Okidok. That works for color, but AxesStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.001]} only changes the horizontal axes's thickness. not vertical.? Also, adding FontFamily->"Helvetica" in the options list causes an error even though adding this last thing does correct the previous issue and it does change the ticks to Helvetica.

Comment: Please see my answer

Comment: Where is your other `PairedHistogram` question?

Comment: I deleted it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = Transpose@
   Table[{RandomInteger[{1, 10}], RandomInteger[{1, 10}]}, {100}];
PairedHistogram[data[[1]], data[[2]], PlotRange -> {All, All}, 
 BarOrigin -> "XAxis", ChartBaseStyle -> {EdgeForm[None]}, 
 ChartStyle -> {{Blue, Orange}, None, None}, 
 ChartLegends -> {"A", "B"}, ImageSize -> 300, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 AxesStyle -> {Directive[Orange, FontFamily -> "Helvetica",  FontSize -> 20], 
               Directive[Blue, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 20]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Excellent, that works, thanks.